# Test Policy File service without Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, crossdomain.xml, cross-domain-policy

I have a Policy File service written in Node.js (Windows 7 environment). I simply want to test that the service returns the policy when a request is made over port 843, but without using Flash (i.e. Telnet, Browser, Powershell, Python, anything really.)

I've looked extensively but can't find any solution that does this. I have attempted with Telnet, but on connection, any keypress at all causes the server to return a bad response (presumably because the request didn't contain the requisite `<policy-file-request/>\0` data.)

Is this possible?

Comment: Change your service to wait for more data if what's read is incomplete, up to 60 seconds at least for debugging, and go with telnet.

Comment: @Vesper thanks for your reply! I was just about to reply to this actually since I was able to figure it out. The service was set to `on (data)` which essentially meant it was watching for a single keypress and as such, was failing. It was some Gist I found and had attempted to use. Telnet did the trick for me for testing, and for the policy file, I ended up scrapping my custom one and going with [this policy file server package](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/FlashPolicyFileServer).

Comment: @Vesper if you'd like, please feel free to post Telnet as an answer and I'll mark it as such. That is really the main question I was aiming to answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rebuild your service to wait for more data if there is incomplete data. Then you will be able to use Telnet to debug the service.